# Adjusted Worldwide Box Office

Tags: box-office

Whenever I read a list of the top box office of all time adjusted for inflation, it's always just domestic.  I understand you've got different currencies and what not.  But, it isn't impossible to figure out currency adjustments to get every movie in terms of American dollar values and then adjust for inflation.  Does anyone know of a list that figures out worldwide gross adjusted for inflation?

Comment: As someone who studies international films, I am very interested in this. I think there should be a way to make the correlation work. For example, the film "Sholay" is one of the top grossing Indian films ever, and ran for over ten years. It was released in 1975. So if one Rupee was worth X dollars in 1975, and you averaged that rate over the entire run of the film, then adjusted it for inflation at the same rate as the dollar (using the current dollar as the constant), wouldn't that yield an appropriate, if not 100% exact result? We know the total amount of money the film took in, we know the

Comment: Getting a good list of local-currency receipts for the top ten markets would be a good start. The currency conversion isn't the hard part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currency conversion rates can change multiple times in a minute, and can vary widely in a day, a week, a month, or a year. So which conversion rate do you use? The closing rate on the day the movie came out? The average rate for the year of production?  And inflation rates vary country to country throughout history. Again, which rate do you use?  Also some currencies disappear over time (think of the Euro replacing a number of individual countries' currencies). It seems like it would be very difficult, if not impossible, to come up with a methodology for calculation that would be consistent. If the goal is to be able to compare one movie to others, then consistency is essential.

Comment: Except every international business has to do just this all the time. Given that getting a good approximation of box office receipts is all that is required (not an auditable set of financial accounts) this shouldn't be too hard, just tedious. You could for example use year end exchange rates from a source like the Economist where such tables exist continuously to times before photography was invented.

Answer (score 3):

I'm from Brazil. I do not speak English, so used google translator to write this

Adjusted WORLDWIDE Box Office

FOREIGN BOX OFFICE ADJUSTED BY DOMESTIC INFLATION

top

**1-  TITANIC US$ 3,500,000,000 (including 3D release)**

*(titanic release 1997 only US$ 3,160,000,000)*

2 - GONE WITH THE WIND US$ 3,250,000,000

3 - AVATAR US$ 2,850,000,000

4 - STAR WARS NEW HOPE US$ 2,360,000,000

5 - E.T US$ 2,075,000,000

6 - THE SOUND OF MUSIC US$ 2.060.000.000

7 - 10 COMANDAMENTS US$ 1.930.000.000

8 - JAWS US$ 1,860,000,000

9 - DOUTOR ZHIVAGO US$ 1.780.000.000

10 - JURASSIC PARK US$ 1,770,000,000

11 - SNOW WHITE US$ 1.760.000.000

12 - LIONKING US$ 1,650,000,000 (including 3D release)

13 - EXORCIST US$ 1,580,000,000

14 - STAR WARS Ep 1 (1999) US$ 1,560,000,000 (including 3D release)

FOREIGN BOX OFFICE ADJUSTED BY DOMESTIC INFLATION

so we get a fairer basis, and the box office with Major tax revenues abroad are not harmed

Comment: Hi.  Can you explain what 'Major recadação abroad are not harmed" means.  That's the only remaining unclear point.

Comment: EXAMPLE

movie "A" and "B" were launched in plumb day and year

movie "A" has 100 worldwide box office and 20 of domestica

movie "B" has 50 bilhetrria world of being 30 domestica

when spending a few years people will wonder how the ticket would be adjusted

so how do list adjusted domestica

they're going to think that movie "B" set is larger than the movie "A", domestically speaking because "B" is greater than "A" EVEN IN THE WORLD THE MOVIE "A" IS THE GREATEST

Answer (score -1):

it is all depends on currency conversion of that particular local currency and all together show it as one currency will varies for each region wise. [Box office Trade](http://boxofficereporter.com/movie-schedules-2017) always specifically significant plan.